# play audio clip in android

Tags: android

I am developing an educational software. There will be a gridview of alphabets available.
I want it to play an audio clip which says the alphabet when someone clicks it. Can you tell me how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sound = MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this, R.raw.splashsound);
    sound.start();

Answer (score 0):

Put your sound file in the assets folder.  Use the AssetManager class to retrieve the sound file.  When you hear the click to play the counds, create an instance of the MediaPlayer, and play the file.

Each of these will require a little digging on how to use each of the classes.

Comment: thank you for solving my problem